# The workings of getopts OPTIND

Tags: bash, getopts

I want to understand how `OPTIND` works by `getopts`.  If I want to skip the first few positional arguments, how should I set up `OPTIND` exactly ?

And because OPTIND is not reset automatically, I need to know how exactly to manually reset between multiple calls to getopts.

Because on the first call I get the error being reported

```
gopi -z
/usr/local/bin/bash: option requires an argument -- z
```

But the second call, the error is not reported

```
gopi -z
```

This is the function

```
 gopi ()
 {

  local parg=""
  while (( $# > 0 )); do
    parg="$1"
    case $parg in
     ("-s"|"--silent") opstring=":n:z:" ;;
     (*) break ;;
    esac  # case ends here
    shift 1
  done
 
  while getopts "$opstring" opname; do
   case ${opname} in
     ("n") dothis ;;
     ("z") dothat ;;
     (?)
       ## Invalid Option Found
       echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" 1>&2
       exit 1
       ;;
     (:)
       ## Required option argument not found
       echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument" 1>&2
       exit 1
       ;;
   esac
  done
 }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP is multi-posting on multiple sites from multiple logins as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And because OPTIND is not reset automatically, I need to know how exactly to manually reset between multiple calls to getopts.

Bash's man page says (under the `getopts` description):

> `OPTIND` is initialized to 1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked.

which hints that resetting it to `1` should work. [This is more clearly spelled out in the POSIX description of `getopts`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html):

> If the application sets *OPTIND* to the value 1, a new set of parameters can be used: either the current positional parameters or new arg values. Any other attempt to invoke getopts multiple times in a single shell execution environment with parameters (positional parameters or arg operands) that are not the same in all invocations, or with an *OPTIND* value modified to be a value other than 1, produces unspecified results.

Here, the second call to `foo` misses the first argument `-a`, but the last call to `foo` again sees both arguments:

```
foo() {
    echo --
    while getopts abc opt; do
        echo $opt
    done
}
foo -abc
foo -a -b
OPTIND=1
foo -a -b
```

Of course it makes more sense to set `OPTIND=1` at the beginning of the function, before calling `getopts`.

---

Note that it's not really useful to look into the value of `OPTIND`. It's not the full truth, as it doesn't contain information about the position inside a single command line argument. E.g. with the argument `-abc` in the first invocation of `foo` above, `OPTIND` takes the values 1, 1, 2 within the loop, with the current character position invisible. (In Bash and ksh, that is. Zsh seems to reset `OPTIND` when entering a function, and yash encodes the position within an argument in the `OPTIND` value.)

Comment: You are quite right about the usefulness of looking at `OPTIND`.  It is a variable important for `getepts` itself, but certainly not for users.  Values for  `OPTIND` got shown for option arguments, meaning that using `echo "OPTIND: $OPTIND`  just after the while clause does not print each positional argument one by one, many are skipped because of the way that `gotepts` processes the positional parameters.

Comment: What I need to do is `OPTIND=1` every time the function is called.  Perhaps one should include `OPTIND=1` as the first thing to do in the function, but it is reset every time the function is called?

Comment: @Ephram, yes, it would make sense to set `OPTIND=1` as the first thing in the function. I just didn't do that here for the sake demonstration.

Comment: Would it make sense to define `OPTIND` as a local variable, i.e. `local OPTIND=1` ?

Comment: @Ephram, I don't know, try it :) I don't think you'll get full use of it being local in the shells that have the hidden variable for the character position, since because of that you likely still couldn't call a function using `getopts` from with a `while getopts` loop.

Comment: If I have multiple functions using it,could there be a conflict?

Comment: After calling getopts I am also doing  `shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"` as the value would be on the position of the next argument after the options defined by `getopts`.

Comment: Doing `shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"` is good right ? Or are the quotes not needed ?

Comment: @Ephram, right, yes, `shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"` would be the way to get rid of the options that were processed in the `getopts` loop. You _probably_ don't need the quotes there, but if for whatever reason `IFS` contains some of the digits that appear in the result, then without the quotes, the result would be mangled. E.g. like in `IFS=2; foo=123; echo $foo`. If you need to ask about quoting expansion in POSIXy shells, just quote them. :)

Comment: You are right, I get a space instead of the digit `2`.  Whilst with quoting I get the correct number printed.

Comment: Originally I defined `OPTIND` as a local variable, but realised it only makes sense for it to be a global variable.